# Clean data in scala

Tags: scala

How to remove '[', ']' and white space from the following data -

```
val fileMat = Array("[1.0,  6.0]",
                "[2.0,  8.0]",
                "[3.0,  10.0]",
                "[3.0,  10.0]",
                "[4.0,  12.0]",
                "[5.0,  14.0]"
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything but digits, `.`s, and `,`s from your list of strings, you can use `str.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", "")`. A full example is below:

```
scala> val fileMat = Array("[1.0,  6.0]",
     |                 "[2.0,  8.0]",
     |                 "[3.0,  10.0]",
     |                 "[3.0,  10.0]",
     |                 "[4.0,  12.0]",
     |                 "[5.0,  14.0]"
     |                )
fileMat: Array[String] = Array([1.0,  6.0], [2.0,  8.0], [3.0,  10.0], [3.0,  10.0], [4.0,  12.0], [5.0,  14.0])

scala> val cleanedData = fileMat.map(_.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", ""))
cleanedData: Array[String] = Array(1.0,6.0, 2.0,8.0, 3.0,10.0, 3.0,10.0, 4.0,12.0, 5.0,14.0)

scala> cleanedData.foreach(println)
1.0,6.0
2.0,8.0
3.0,10.0
3.0,10.0
4.0,12.0
5.0,14.0
```